# How can I use tea to replicate the look of ammonia fumed wood?

Tags: staining

A [comment](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/267/which-woods-work-well-with-ammonia#comment306_269) by [dfife](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/users/3/dfife) on the Q&A [Which woods work well with ammonia?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/267/which-woods-work-well-with-ammonia) says:

> You can also soak any piece of wood in tea (or something else high in tannins) and give it a higher degree of tannins. I've done this quite successfully with pine and poplar.

I would like to try this, but have some questions about the process:

- How long should I soak the wood for? Does the length of time vary by species or by how strongly the tea has been brewed?
- Will the wood warp as it dries, and if so, how can I minimize that?
- Does the color change as the wood dries? If so, how much, and does the grain become more or less emphasized?

Comment: Thanks for posting! Unfortunately, you're asking too many questions all at once, and it will be difficult for anyone to provide a single definitive answer. Please try to focus your question more, and ask additional separate questions if necessary. The answers to some of the questions you've posed here will be subjective. Also, wood species, type and strength of the tea, etc., will undoubtedly introduce a lot of variance to anyone's results and the best way to answer them would be for you to experiment yourself.

Comment: Niall, these are good questions! Please edit it and submit multiple questions!

Comment: It's closed as too broad, but these questions are likely to arise at the same time for anyone planning on trying out such a finish. My opinion is that those questions should be answered in the same place, and the question be made more "singular" e.g. "What are the potential problems of  applying tea as a stain?", as opposed to broken up in unrelated questions.  The specificity of the answers on this forum is high, and I'm sure answers to the larger question will cover many aspects such as "warping", "pitfalls", "preparation" etc. Then if anything is left unanswered it could be asked elsewhere.